# Android braintree SDK - Paypal showing different company name in T&C view

Tags: android, paypal, braintree

HI I am using BrainTree sdk in our application, in conjunction with PayPal for making payments and while creating sandbox merchantId, public key and private key we registered company name as some "Dummy Software". In the api call we got the client-token generated at our server side and using that we created a BrainTree instatnce as

```
    mBraintree = Braintree.getInstance(this, getClientToken());
    mBraintree.setIntegrationDropin();
    mBraintree.sendAnalyticsEvent("sdk.initialized");
```

but When I go to the paypal login view after logging in, it is saying some "Jacunski Software asks that you:......." instead of "Dummy Software asks that you:.......". How can I solve this issue, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if the snippet of code you posted is from your app or just an example, but only the first line is necessary for custom integrations.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, you can always [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

In sandbox mode, you don't connect to your actual PayPal account, so you'll see the name of our test account. In production, you'll see the name of your real account.

We'll update the name of the test account to make it more clear what's going on; thanks for the report.

Comment: Hi, I didn't tried what you have suggested as it may take sometime but in the IOS sdk we are able to get the exact company name even in sandbox mode